2023 Moderator Election Q&A – Question Collection

The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it here.


Bitcoin Stack Exchange is scheduled for an election next week, 2023-10-10. In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.
Here’s how it’ll work:

Until the nomination phase, (so, until 2023-10-10 at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post one question per answer.

If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of [text](link), as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.

This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into currently.

We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The following two questions are guaranteed to be included:

How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc. a question that you feel shouldn’t have been?


The community team may also include the following three questions if the community doesn’t supply enough questions.

In your opinion, what do moderators do?
A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching enough reputation to access moderator tools or become a trusted user?


At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. We exclude any suggested questions that are negatively scored.

We will post the final questionnaire on the Election page. Candidates will have the option to fill out the questionnaire, and their answers will appear beneath their intro statements.
This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.



If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Apologies for the delay in posting this - our tools are not working as expected at the moment but we're working on fixing them. If you would like, I can leave the question collection open a bit longer than scheduled.

Folks who may be thinking of running can check their mod score here

"If you have questions about the election process itself, please ask your question on the Bitcoin Meta." How free is discussion? I one finds out that a nominee has been convicted of a felony, can that be mentioned here?

@MichaelHardy That seems like a very... specific thing to ask. I'm not sure quite how to respond to it. What you're quoting relates more to the actual election process, meaning the phases of the election and such things. Issues related to participants should be handled in the usual sorts of ways - through flags or the contact form. In general, if you want to get our attention to a user who has nominated in the election, feel free to flag their nomination with an explanation. This will ping me (the election leader) to review the flag.

"Flag their nomination"? To what extent would one be allowed to criticize candidates by providing factual information and arguing that it is a reason why a person should not be a moderator? Is that to be done only by flagging?

@MichaelHardy There's a comments section under candidate nominations that can be used to ask questions of the candidate's use of the site and tools and other behavior as well as to get deeper understanding of their answers to the questionnaire but I should be clear that accusing or otherwise attacking the users will not be acceptable, particularly as it relates to things that have nothing to do with use of this site that are impossible for others to confirm. If you have accusations for why a candidate should be deemed ineligible, it's better to flag rather than commenting.


What are your criteria for upvoting a question?  What are your criteria for downvoting?



As a moderator of the Bitcoin Stack Exchange site, what would you do to improve engagement on the site?



What is your opinion around comments remaining on questions and answers after they become somewhat stale?  What do you consider "somewhat stale" to mean?


As a moderator, how would you approach a poorly phrased question that asks about an interesting issue?
